# Pythonによる一人称視点の迷路生成

Tags: python, python3, processing

過去にprocessingのpythonバージョンで迷路を作り、キーボード操作で動かしたり、視点を２次元の見下ろし型にしたり視点を一人称にしたりしましたが、processingを使わずにpythonで作ろうとしたとき、どうにも同じようなものができません。なにかいいライブラリや考え方がありましたら、ご享受ください。

Comment: こんにちは。Shunyaさんは、Pythonで最初どうやって作ろうとしましたか。そして、どこが「同じようなもの」にならなかったのですか。

Comment: @apple502jさん
ごもっともなご指摘ありがとうございます。

最初はprocessingをそのままコピペして、エラーが出たところだけ直して作ろうとしました。しかし、processingで
    '''size(800,600,P3D)'''
とできるところがpythonだけでは解決できなかったので質問しました。